# Will a battery be damaged when in series with a low frequency AC signal source?

Tags: power-electronics

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcO278.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Imagine the 5V voltage source as a battery. If I place it in series with a signal generator will I ruin the battery? Also is it safe to place the battery and the signal generator in parallel?

Comment: It's not safe to put in parallel, that might kill the signal generator.

Answer (score 2):

> Imagine the 5V voltage source as a battery. If I place it in series with a signal generator will I ruin the battery? Also is it safe to place the battery and the signal generator in parallel?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhidwC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The OP's circuit redrawn.*

If we redraw your circuit we can see that the there can be current flow in and out of the battery.

- When V2 < V1 the battery will be discharged at a rate of \$ I = \frac {V1 - V2}{R1} \$. This should be OK.
- When V2 > V1 the battery will be charged by V2.
  Whether this is safe or not depends on the battery chemistry (is it rechargeable) and the safe charging current.

> Also is it safe to place the battery and the signal generator in parallel?

Again, you it depends on the voltages.

- If the signal generator has a decoupling capacitor on the output then

  - On initial connection it has to be able to survive the DC kick back through the capacitor.
  - The capacitor has to be rated to withstand the DC voltage.
- If there is no decoupling capacitor then the output stage has to be able to survive driving into a current sourcing load.

Are you still trying to solve https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246694/earth-fault-monitoring-system?

Comment: Yes I am. I have a working prototype but I'm trying out new configurations. I'm happy to share with you if you're interested :)

Comment: Not until you supply the info requested in the comments on the other questions. ;^)

Answer (score 1):

Lab signal generators are usually 50 Ohms internal so this would be like connecting -5V with 50 Ohms to a sig gen. output. As they often can drive much high voltages > 20Vpp, I see  no obvious which this voltage or reverse current should cause problems on a good design .

Battery ESR is determine by voltage drop at some rated current or voltage rise at some rated charge current, so this would only be charging and discharging the battery with 50mA at midpoint of the swing. This is not much and power dissipated in the battery depends on internal ESR.

It's not something you do to a IC sig. gen or battery, so it is hypothetical but not obviously harmful since the resistor limits the current but could damage a CMOS square wave gen.

If one wanted to measure the ESR or State of Charge in a Battery, one uses a generator to drive a low impedance transistor switch with a narrow pulse and examine the voltage drop and current rise with less power than the transistor rated pulse power and same for R and this ratio is the ESR of the battery.  The ESR will rise sharply as the battery depletes below 10% SOC and then if fully charged, gives an indication of aging of the battery compared to new ones with similar Ah capacity.  The switched series resistor would consume all the power a battery is designed to supply such as C/20 or C1 in where C1 is the Ah rating for 20 hrs divided by 20 to test a 1 hr discharge capacity.  Thus current depends on C and Ah rating of battery and if done in 1/10 second with repeated tests, gives the batteries internal series resistance or ESR. This is a quality and age figure of merit of the battery capacity.

The ESR or RdsOn of the switch must then be near the same or less as the battery to withstand this current and heat dissipation.

Comment: So if I used a battery above 40V I might be causing trouble? Should I add a capacitor to block the DC signal then?

Comment: That depends on Purpose of your circuit, output stage design etc. But generally yes, if not knowing details. Otherwise it's a good way to find out how things fail.

Comment: Generally you never apply more DC voltage and current externally in parallel than it can generate internally to an outside load. This might be worst case , more or less.